# Передача данных с помощью SharedPreferences

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, android-shared-preferences, firebase-android

Я создаю в базе данных каталог с клубами, в котором должны храниться id и название клуба:

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Clubs")
val clubId = ref.push().key
    
val clubMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
clubMap["clubId"] = clubId!!
clubMap["clubname"] = name_club.text.toString()          
    
ref.child(clubId).updateChildren(clubMap)
```

Далее все клубы я помещаю в RecyclerView. Когда я нажимаю по конкретному клубу, я должен попасть в фрагмент этого клуба, передав ему id клуба:

```
holder.clubLayout.setOnClickListener {

            val editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()

            editor.putString("clubId", club.getClubid())
            editor.apply()

            (mContext as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.clubs_container, ClubFragment()).commit()
        }
```

И в фрагменте я получаю это id:

```
val preferences = context?.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
if (preferences != null)
{
    clubId = preferences.getString("clubId", "none").toString()
}
```

Далее я хочу получить название клуба с помощью id клуба и записать его в `club_fragment_club_name`:

```
    private fun clubInfo()
    {
        val clubsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Clubs").child(clubId)

        clubsRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener
        {
            @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)
            {
                if (p0.exists())
                {
                    val club = p0.getValue<Clubs>(Clubs::class.java)

                    club_fragment_club_name.text = club!!.getClubname()
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError)
            {

            }
        })
    }
```

Но `club_fragment_club_name` получается пустым. То есть там нет названия клуба, он просто пустой. В чём может быть проблема?

upd: Когда я попытался id пользователя, то всё было хорошо. То есть проблема не в самой передаче информации, а в id клуба. Но я без понятия, почему это не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще на мой взгляд довольно странно использовать для передачи данных в фрагмент функционала для хранения данных приложения. Более логично как мне кажется было бы использовать Bundle в который вы будете класть ваш id. Здесь вы переходите на фрагмент:

```
(mContext as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.clubs_container, ClubFragment()).commit()
```

можно сделать так:

```
val clubFrg = ClubFragment()
clubFrg.arguments = Bundle().apply {
      putInt("clubId", club.getClubid())
}

(mContext as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.clubs_container, clubFrg ).commit()
```

дальше вы ловите данные в целевом фрагменте:

```
val clubID = arguments.getInt("clubId")
```

так же, если все-таки у вас не пробросятся данные, посмотрите в список через логи или отладку, точно ли там есть идентификатор.

Comment: Я всё это сделал - не помогает. У меня в адаптере есть строчка с именем клуба. И имя клуба `club.getClubname()` он получает, то есть я вижу имя. А вот если я поставлю `club.getClubid()`, то пустота. Как будто в id у меня ничего нет

Comment: так у вас может идентификатора нет?)

Comment: вполне возможно. А можно, пожалуйста, поподробнее? Раньше я как-то вроде обходился

Comment: что значит обходились? я вам в ответе привел более логичный вариант передачи данных в фрагмент, так как при помощи префов такое не делается, но если у вас нет id у вашего клуба, то передать вы не сможете его, что как-бы логично)

Comment: просто понимаете, я в вопросе, в самом начале, показал, как я создал этот id. В firebase он тоже есть, но я не могу его получить. Может быть, ошибка в самом создании id?

Comment: посмотрите через логи или отладку как и что вы по итогу создали, тогда будет проще рассуждать о том что правильно а что нет

Comment: Всё, я решил проблему, спасибо большое вам)